# How to use the yammer API for subscription

Tags: subscription, yammer

I am totally new to yammer API. I need the subscription code, i've created a code but its not at all working, I am stucked in it. please help me out. The following is the code which i used.

```
   yam.config({appId: "Kcab3g7Y5P1y1g0H05Bve"});
   function post() {
    yam.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
    var target_id = '4583632';
    var target_user = "user";
        if (response.authResponse) {
            yam.request(
              {
        url : "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/subscriptions"
              , method: "GET" 
              , data: { target_id : target_id,target_type:target_user }
              , success: function (msg) { 
         for(var key in msg) {
           var value = msg[key];
           alert("success "+value);
         }

         }
              , error: function (msg) {
                  for(var key in msg) {
            var value = msg[key];
            alert("err "+value);
          } 
              }
              }
            );
        } 
    });
}
```

Waiting for the reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the code you posted exactly what you are trying to do. The following code illustrates how you can check if the currently logged on user is following (subscribed to) another Yammer user with the id: 1514517708. I discovered the id for the user by looking at the user in my Yammer network on the Yammer website and copying the user's feedId from the URL. For this to work you'll need to use an id for a user in your Yammer network and also replace the appId value with the id of the app you configure in your network.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Yammer App</title>
    <script src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js"></script>
    <script>
        yam.config({ appId: "[your appId goes here]" });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='post()'>Check following!</button>
    <script>
        function post() {
            yam.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    check_subscription_to_user(1514517708);
                } else {
                    yam.login(function (response) {
                        if (!response.authResponse) {
                            check_subscription_to_user(1514517708);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };

        function check_subscription_to_user(id) {
            yam.request(
               {
                   url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/subscriptions/to_user/" + id + ".json"
               , method: "GET"
               , success: function (msg) { alert("You are following: " + id); }
               , error: function (msg) { alert("You are not following" + id); }
               }
           );
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For other operations on subscriptions, see the REST API docs here: https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-subscriptions